# Creating a Simple Store in SAP Hybris 6

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new in Hybris 6, i would like to create a simple eCommerce store where i can select products and check out as normal using the basic recipe. I would like to know how  to do that from END to END. I know the whole theory and i have the material the only thing i am interested in in the various steps i must follow to create a fully functional simple store. Currently i can do the data modelling and classifications, import data using ImpEx, I can view and customize the available electronics and apparel stores however the problem is i want to create mine from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *modulegen* ant target, it creates all you need for your future store implementation.

```
ant modulegen
accelerator
myshop
com.mycompany.myshop
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have followed the steps you gave me however i want to find out how i can access my shop? Is there a default data model that i can work with so as  to import my products?

Comment: Yes use the electronicstore extension.